# Getting start 3 word (string) from field using ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.0, vbscript

I would like to know can I write vbscript to class field from start 3 words

[image]

for example If start AAA = "Apple"
else start BBBB = "Boat"
else start CCC = "Cat"

Comment: Slice the string like `thestring[:3]` and https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000022370

Comment: Are you trying to field calculate or to label using ArcMap and vbScript?  Are you really using ArcMap 10.0?

Answer (score 1):

You're better off using python, VBScript is not supported in ArcGIS Pro so no point learning it as ArcMap is on the way out.

Expression:

```
myfunc(!Title_FLNA!)
```

In the code block:

```
def myfunc(value):
    if value.startswith('AAA'):
        return 'Apple'
    elif value.startswith('BBBB'):
        return 'Boat'
    elif value.startswith('CCC'):
        return 'Cat'
    else:
        return value  # important if you're overwriting the field,
                      # make sure you return a default value if nothing matches
```